# Populate TableView with not observable data

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm really new to java and javaFX but I need this stuff to accomplish an obligatory exercise.

So far I coded a console program for importing csv values and make some comparisons on the values. But now the task is to create a GUI for the same stuff. So I want to use the same code coded for CSVimport and comparison for the GUI, but I don't know for example how to populate a `TableView` (`TableColumn`) with my data which is not coded as `StringProperty` or `DoubleProperty` etc. All Tutorials which I found (for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) or [here](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part2/)) use those Properties. So how can I use regular Strings or doubles to populate a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a POJO such as

```
public class Person {

  // ...

  public String getName() { 
      return name ;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Then you can just do

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> cellData) {
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getName());
    }
});
```

In JavaFX 8, the last statement becomes

```
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()));
```